# im trying to compare between two dates 'Saturday, May 1, 2017' and '2017-07-23' but the first one is stored as string

Tags: mysql, sql, date

(Date_time  = 'Saturday, May 1, 2017')

select Date_time from dates where Date_time < '2017-07-23'

Comment: I need to add 3 and 4, but I can't use '+'.

Comment: Can't use str_to_date - I disagree.

Comment: i know i cant i dont know how to compare them !

Comment: I would use str_to_date() (assuming, I was unable to provide the date_time in a more suitable manner to begin with)

Comment: i tried str_to_date('Date_time',"%Y.%m.%d") it gave me nulls

Comment: read up on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set @d ='Saturday, May 1, 2017';

select case
            when str_to_date(@d,'%W, %M %d, %Y') < '2017-07-23' then true else false end testit;

+--------+
| testit |
+--------+
|      1 |
+--------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Assuming the month is not abbreviated and all date_times are in the same format
,2 facts that should be included in your question.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: @AboodJayyousi . . . Then you should *accept* the answer.